# How to iterate through slices at the last dimension

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

For example, you have array

```
a = np.array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
               [ 3,  4,  5]],

              [[ 6,  7,  8],
               [ 9, 10, 11]]])
```

We want to iterate through slices at the last dimension, i.e. [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9,10,11]. Any way to achieve this without the for loop? Thanks!

Tried this but it does not work, because numpy does not interpret the tuple in the way we wanted - `a[(0, 0),:]` is not the same as `a[0, 0, :]`

```
[a[i,:] for i in zip(*product(*(range(ii) for ii in a.shape[:-1])))]
```

More generally, any way for the last k dimensions? Something equivalent to looping through `a[i,j,k, ...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [26]: a = np.array([[[ 0,  1,  2], 
    ...:                [ 3,  4,  5]], 
    ...:  
    ...:               [[ 6,  7,  8], 
    ...:                [ 9, 10, 11]]])                                                                
In [27]: [a[i,j,:] for i in range(2) for j in range(2)]                                                
Out[27]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
```

or

```
In [31]: list(np.ndindex(2,2))                                                                         
Out[31]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
In [32]: [a[i,j] for i,j in np.ndindex(2,2)]
```

another

```
list(a.reshape(-1,3))
```